# AngularJS directive's element sometimes not defined in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

I keep getting this weird error, which only seem to happen on Firefox: I have an element tag, say `<directive-element></directive-element>` and the following directive for it:

```
app.directive('directiveElement', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<input type="text" />',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            element.on('focus', function()
            {
                // Do something with element
                // for instance, call element.scrollLeft();
            });
        }

    }
})
```

Every once in a while, Firefox throws me an error, saying `scrollLeft()` cannot be called on a null. I tried console logging the `element` itself, and it is an Angular element, but of length 0.

I don't understand how this can be an issue since the `input`, and all the binding are injected ONCE angular finds the directive `<directive-element />`. So if I can see the input, that means Angular produced it. So why wouldn't the element be available?

What can be the cause of this? This seems pretty random. All I have to do is refresh the page I am on over and over and eventually this happens (i.e. I don't do ANYTHING else other than refreshing, and sometimes I can this error). And this is again only on Firefox.

Comment: Try changing to `<directive-element></directive-element>`, it might helps.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I have already tried that. I don't understand how element is undefined IF angular found the directive and loaded the template!

Comment: just a guess, try adding replace: true in the return object

Comment: I did, I still get the error randomly.

Comment: `<directive-element/>` is **never** correct according to the HTML specification. If it works you are lucky, because a compliant browser must not support it. Only certain native elements are allowed to be declared that way.